# What is a fast grid implementation in mono?

Tags: .net, mono, grid

I do need sorting, filtering, row and column hiding, and column reordering.

I've been trying to get DataGridView to fit my needs but it seems too slow in Mono (fine when run native).  I've tried manually updating the rows as well as using a custom datasource (my data is not coming from a database).  When you have around 1000 cells visible (66 rows by 15 columns), even moving the focus from cell to cell is slow and puts a big load on the CPU.  I'm not using autosizing columns.

I don't need edit functionality.

Comment: I can do the sorting and filtering outside of the grid, if necessary.

Comment: BTW, when I run in Mono, it's in Linux.

Comment: Does the same performance problem exist in Mono on Windows?

Comment: I haven't installed Mono on Windows yet.

Comment: I guess I'll try a ListView in detail mode.  Should be more light-weight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListView seems to work fine, as long as the data is updated row-by-row instead of cell-by-cell.

I had to subclass it and turn on DoubleBuffer to stop the flicker.